# how to use @Service annotation in Spring MVC to create the bean of Service layer

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Can someone tell how to get the bean of service layer in spring MVC. One way to get the bean of service layer is by using @Service annotation but how to do that, I don't know.
Controller:

```
@Controller
public class ConfigureApplicationController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/ConfigureApplication.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getListOfAllConfigureApplication(){

        AppConfigureServiceImpl getService=new AppConfigureServiceImpl();

        ArrayList<ConfigureApplication> results =getService.getListOfAllAppConfigure();
        ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("ConfigureApplication");
        model.addObject("results",results);
        return model;
    }
```

and serviceImpl is:

```
@Service("appConfigureServiceImpl")
public class AppConfigureServiceImpl implements AppConfigureService {

    public ArrayList<ConfigureApplication> getListOfAllAppConfigure(){

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ApplicationContext ctx=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml");
        AppConfigureDAOImpl getAll=ctx.getBean("appConfigureDAOImpl", AppConfigureDAOImpl.class);

        ArrayList<ConfigureApplication> results =getAll.getList();
        return results;
    }
```

In this i have made the object of AppConfigureServiceImpl (in service layer)then i invoke the method but by doing so i am not using dependency injection in spring. I know i can do this using @Service annotation but i don';t know the syntax. can someone help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

put a plain @Service annotation over your AppConfigureServiceImpl (you don't have to specify the "appConfigureServiceImpl" like you did).

Then have the service instance injected automatically in your controller by adding the following inside ConfigureApplicationController class:

```
@Autowired
AppConfigureService appConfigureService;
```

Now you can just call it like this: `appConfigureService.getListOfAllAppConfigure();`

Note that for the injection to happen, you need to make sure that you have set componentScan property in your configuration file to scan the packages that contain the classes to be injected. In your case, the package that contains AppConfigureServiceImpl.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.my.servicepackage" />
```

Note also that you should do the same with your dao instead of creating a new application context and getting it from the there. I.e. add a

```
@Autowired
AppConfigureDAO appConfigureDAO;
```

property inside your AppConfigureServiceImpl and use that.